# how do i install pip in debian linux withour sudo access. python version using 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.6

i am not able to install pip withour sudo access. I wont get sudo access . So is there any alternate to that. I am able to setup virtualenv and access python but pip install is not working .

which pip is returning /usr/bin/pip

Comment: Did your python come bundled with pip?  See if you can run pip commands like `python3 -m pip help`

Comment: did you activate virtualenv? once it's active, `which pip` should point to the venv's pip instance and you should be good to go.

Comment: You can't do that because /usr/bin/ is for *system-wide* binaries, so you have to create environment for your own user before you can install anything, once you have that, you won't need sudo access. I hopefully don't need to explain why you need permissions to modify what system-wide python has installed.

Comment: try installing packages using `easy_install` using `--user` flag, It doesn't require `sudo`